# How can I format the input thats been used on Redux Form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have the following input component and I would like to format some of the fields like DOB to be xx/xx/xxxx and for card input xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

Can anyone tell me how is the best to do it? I've tried to add onChange function but seem to not work

This is my component

```
const createRenderer = render => ({ input, meta, placeholder, ...rest }) => (
  <div className="form-group">
    {render(input, placeholder, rest, meta)}
  </div>
);

const RenderInput = createRenderer((input, placeholder, { children }, meta, onChange) => (
  <input
    className="form-control"
    placeholder={placeholder}
    {...input}
    style={{ borderColor: meta.error && meta.touched ? "red" : "black" }}
  />
));
```

Comment: I don't get you clearly.
In short, you want to do some sort of validation on the fields 
You could use `regular expressions` if this is the case.

Comment: @zonecc the validation I've made it as you can see I have `meta.error` what I want to do is to use something like `.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1/$2/')`

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form-input-masks